# Spring testing controllers with BasicAuth on and custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, security, testing, mocking, role

I am making a rest api. Recently, I have added Basic Auth to the project and specified the configuration like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public final static String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    public final static String ROLE_USER = "USER";

    /**
     * Determines the resource access for different account types
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/create").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    /**
     * Initially fills Spring Security with default accounts
     */
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {

        final Properties users = new Properties();
        users.put("user","pass,ROLE_USER,enabled"); //login = user, password = pass
        users.put("admin","pass,ROLE_ADMIN,enabled"); //login = admin, password = pass
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }
}
```

I have also made some controllers and some tests for them:

Controllers:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("MovieService")//not relevant
    private MovieService ms;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("CastService")//not relevant
    private CastService cs;

    @RequestMapping(value = "admin/movies", method = GET)
    public List<Movie> selectAllMovies(){

        return ms.selectAll();
    }

//the rest of the code..
}
```

And tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class MovieControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Mock
    private CastService castService;

    @Mock
    private ActorService actorService;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private MovieController movieController;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(movieController).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN", username = "admin", password = "pass")
    @WithUserDetails("admin")
    public void testGetAllMovies() throws Exception {

        List<Movie> movieList = Arrays.asList(
                new Movie("title1", "desc1", MovieType.newest, 10f, true),
                new Movie("title2", "desc2", MovieType.newest, 10f, true),
                new Movie("title3", "desc3", MovieType.newest, 10f, true));

        when(movieService.selectAll()).thenReturn(movieList);

        String uri = "admin/movies";

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        int status = result.getResponse().getStatus();

        verify(movieService, times(1)).selectAll();

        Assert.assertEquals("failure - expected HTTP status 200", 200, status);
        Assert.assertTrue("failure - expected HTTP response body to have a value", content.trim().length() > 0);
    }

//the rest of the code..
}
```

But when I run the tests, I get errors from Mockito that say:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
movieService.selectAll();
-> at com.myproject.Controller.MovieControllerTest.testGetAllMovies(MovieControllerTest.java:87)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

It seems, that Spring security does not allow the tests to call the urls that require authentication ("admin/movies"). As it is specified in config file, this url requires ADMIN role. Funny thing is, when I remove "admin" part of the url in controller and in test, the test works! But, according to config, it still requires authentication with USER role (only "/user/create" doesnt require it, as you can see in config).

I have tried using `@WithMockUser(username="admin", password="pass", roles="ADMIN")` and it doesnt help, the error stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Mockito for MVC test, that seems like an odd thing to do? Normally you would @Autowire the real Controller/Service/Repository directly into the test.

Here is how our base class for MVC test look.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class, classes = IntegrationTestConfiguration.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
    // from some Spring context
    @Autowired
    protected HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager;

    @Autowired
    protected ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection") // this is created by Spring Security
    @Autowired
    protected FilterChainProxy filterChain;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    protected TestSession.LoginDetails integrationTestUserDetails;

    @Before
    public void configureMock() throws InvalidDecryptionKeyException {
        // setup spring MVC
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = get("/");
        requestBuilder.secure(true);
        requestBuilder.header("origin", "http://localhost");
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .addFilter(filterChain)
                .defaultRequest(requestBuilder)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Also when you use MovkMvc, you should remember that you are communicating at the level just above Http, at the point when the servlet container has processed the byte stream into a HttpServletRequest. This means that if you post JSON you would typically create a Java object, serialise it to bytes like this.

```
mvc.perform(post("/internal/signOut")
    .session(mySession)
    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(signOutRequest))));
```

Comment: Hey, I am using Mockito just to become familiar with it. Anyway, thanks for your answer, but it seems that I have found solution to my silly problem :) see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

**OK so it seems that Spring Security had nothing to do with my problem.** The real reason mockito couldnt detect interactions with mocks (the controllers were never interacted with) was that the urls I have put into MockMvcRequestBuilder were incorrect. Only by accident I discovered that the url has to contain slashes at the beginnig of the url string, so I changed: `"admin/movies"` to `"/admin/movies"` and it works, even despite the fact that, as you can see in my code above, in controllers, the mapping for controller is without these slashes ("admin/movies").
Crazy, but true :)